# No Reverse Match error in Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

New to Django and stuck on this error. My template was rendering correctly. The only change I made was adding a '1/0' in my views.py file to simulate a breakpoint. And now the template will not render when I remove it.

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout
from app.views import send_morsel, start_hunt, MorselList, MorselDetailView,\
register, create_morsel, HomePageView, FAQPageView, AboutPageView,\
newsletter_signup, edit_morsel

app_name = 'app'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
    url(r'^morsels/$', MorselList.as_view(), name='morsel_list'),
    url(r'^morsels/send/$', send_morsel, name='morsel_send'),
    url(r'^morsels/(?P<morsel_id>[0-9])/start_hunt/$', start_hunt, name='start_hunt'),
    url(r'^register/', register, name='register'),
    url(r'^faq/$', FAQPageView.as_view(), name='faq'),
    url(r'^about/$', AboutPageView.as_view(), name='about'),
    url(r'^morsels/create/$', create_morsel, name="create_morsel"),
    url(r'^morsels/(?P<morsel_id>[0-9])/edit/$', edit_morsel, name='edit_morsel'),
    url(r'^morsels/(?P<pk>[0-9])/display/$', MorselDetailView.as_view(), name='morsel_detail'),
    url(r'^newsletter_signup/$', newsletter_signup, name='newsletter_signup')
]
```

morsel_list.html

```
{% extends "app/base.html" %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% bootstrap_css %}
{% bootstrap_javascript %}
{% bootstrap_messages %}
{% block content %}
    <h2>Morsels</h2>
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <p>hello</p>
        <p>welcome {{ user.username }}</p>
        <p><a href="/logout">Logout</a></p>
    {% else %}
        <p><a href="/login">Login</a></p>
        <p><a href="/app/register">Register</a></p>
    {% endif %}
    <ul>
        {% for morsel in object_list %}
            <li>{{ morsel.name }} 
                <a href="{%url 'app:morsel_detail' morsel.id%}">View</a>
                <a href="{%url 'app:edit_morsel' morsel.id %}">Edit</a>
                <a href="{%url 'app:start_hunt' morsel.id%}">Send! </a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% if messages %}
        {% for msg in messages %}       
            {% bootstrap_alert msg.message alert_type=msg.level_tag %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Really not sure what to do here.

relevant block from views.py:

```
def edit_morsel(request, morsel_id=None):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        extra = int(request.session['extra'])
        form = MorselCreationForm(request.POST)
        formset = formset_factory(QuestionAnswerCreationForm, extra=extra)(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data["name"]
            start_time = form.cleaned_data["start_time"]
            end_time = form.cleaned_data["end_time"]
            welcome_text = form.cleaned_data["welcome_text"]
            completed_text = form.cleaned_data["completed_text"]
            public_enabled = form.cleaned_data["public_enabled"]
            m = Morsel(
                name=name, 
                start_time = start_time, 
                end_time = end_time, 
                welcome_text = welcome_text, 
                completed_text = completed_text,
                public_enabled = public_enabled
            )
            m.save()
            # this order is important to be able to access the relations
            for form in formset:
                question_text = form.cleaned_data["question_text"]
                q = Question(
                    question_text=question_text,
                    morsel = m
                )
                answer = Answer(question=q)
                q.answer.answer_text = form.cleaned_data["answer_text"]
                q.save()
    morsel = get_object_or_404(Morsel.objects.prefetch_related('questions'), pk=morsel_id)
    form = MorselCreationForm(initial={
        "start_time" : morsel.start_time,
        "end_time" : morsel.end_time,
        "name" : morsel.name,
        "welcome_text" : morsel.welcome_text, 
        "completed_text" : morsel.completed_text,
        "public_enabled" : morsel.public_enabled
    })
    initial_formset_values = [{"question_text":question.question_text,"answer_text":question.answer.answer_text} \
    for question in morsel.questions.select_related("answer").all()]
    formset = formset_factory(QuestionAnswerCreationForm, extra=1, max_num=len(morsel.questions.all()))(initial=initial_formset_values)
    return render(request, 'app/edit_morsel.html', {'form':form, 'formset':formset})
```

Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/app/morsels/

Django Version: 1.11.6
Python Version: 3.6.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'app.apps.AppConfig',
 'django_extensions',
 'twilio',
 'debug_toolbar',
 'bootstrap3',
 'sass_processor']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /Users/kiniadit/code/morsels/app/templates/app/base.html, error at line 12
   Reverse for 'morsel_detail' with arguments '(10,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['app/morsels/(?P<pk>[0-9])/display/$']   2 : <html><head>
   3 :         <meta charset="utf-8">
   4 :         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   5 :         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css">s
   6 :         
   7 :         <!-- Custom links -->
   8 :          <link href="{% static 'app/css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
   9 :         <body>
   10 :         <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-success">
   11 :           <div class="container">
   12 :             <a  class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img sr c="{% static 'app/images/logo.png' %}"></a>
   13 :             <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar2SupportedContent" aria-controls="navbar2SupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> </button>
   14 :             <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center justify-content-end" id="navbar2SupportedContent">
   15 :               <ul class="navbar-nav">
   16 :                 <li class="nav-item">
   17 :                   <a class="nav-link text-white" href="{% url 'app:about' %}">About</a>
   18 :                 </li>
   19 :                 <li class="nav-item">
   20 :                   <a class="nav-link text-white" href="{% url 'app:faq' %}">FAQ</a>
   21 :                 </li>
   22 :               </ul>


Traceback:

File "/Users/kiniadit/code/morsels/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/kiniadit/code/morsels/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  217.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/kiniadit/code/morsels/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  215.                 response = response.render()

File "/Users/kiniadit/code/morsels/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  107.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "/Users/kiniadit/code/morsels/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
  84.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

File "/Users/kiniadit/code/morsels/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  66.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/Users/kiniadit/code/morsels/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  207.                     return self._render(context)

File "/Users/kiniadit/code/morsels/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/utils.py" in instrumented_test_render
  107.     return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/Users/kiniadit/code/morsels/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/Users/kiniadit/code/morsels/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/Users/kiniadit/code/morsels/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  177.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/Users/kiniadit/code/morsels/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/utils.py" in instrumented_test_render
  107.     return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/Users/kiniadit/code/morsels/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/Users/kiniadit/code/morsels/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/Users/kiniadit/code/morsels/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  72.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/Users/kiniadit/code/morsels/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/Users/kiniadit/code/morsels/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/Users/kiniadit/code/morsels/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  216.                     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))

File "/Users/kiniadit/code/morsels/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/Users/kiniadit/code/morsels/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  458.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)

File "/Users/kiniadit/code/morsels/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/base.py" in reverse
  91.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))

File "/Users/kiniadit/code/morsels/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  497.         raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /app/morsels/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'morsel_detail' with arguments '(10,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['app/morsels/(?P<pk>[0-9])/display/$']
```

Comment: What does your `base.html` look like? That seems to be where the error is originating from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex matches a single digit, so it works for `pk=9` but not `pk=10`. Add a `+` so that it matches multiple digits.

```
url(r'^morsels/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/display/$', MorselDetailView.as_view(), name='morsel_detail'),
```

You’ll need to fix your other URL patterns that use `[0-9]` as well.

Answer (score 0):

In your urls.py, you have:  url(r'^morsels/(?P[0-9])/display/$', MorselDetailView.as_view(), name='morsel_detail'), pk(primary key)means you have to name the parameters pk when you make the request. So as the error shows, you try to send a parameters called the morsel.id which suppose to be the pk, so it raise error,so inside you morsel_list.html file, switch View to View, hope this help you.